# Google Spreadsheet- Based on text in different cells, change another cell text

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

please help me to create a simple Google spreadsheet.

### 1st function

*If value/text in cells C3, D3 & E3 ="passed"- change F3's value to "passed" else show "failed"*

### 2nd function

*If value/text in any of the cell is "passed"- change F3's value to "passed" else show "failed"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first function, you would need to enter the following in cell F3:

```
=IF(AND(C3="passed",D3="passed",E3="passed"),"passed","failed")
```

This checks whether C3, D3 and E3 contain "passed" and if so returns "passed". For the second function, this is very similar:

```
=IF(OR(C3="passed",D3="passed",E3="passed"),"passed","failed")
```

This checks whether any of the three cells contain "passed", and if so returns "passed".

Hope that helps! M

Comment: Thanks let me check.

can u help me to create this function?
If value/text in cells C3="done" & D3 & E3's value to "passed" show "success" else show "failed" & any one of the cells shows "not applicable" then show F3's value to "Not applicable"

Comment: Sure, use =IF(OR(C3="not applicable",D3="not applicable",E3="not applicable"),"not applicable", IF(AND(C3="done",D3="passed",E3="passed"),"success","failed"))

Comment: If the functions I've given work, can you please accept the answer to show you are happy?

Comment: Thanks a lot...............

I have 2 more doubts.

1. Is it possible to change color, background & strike through of cell "F3" based on C3,D3,E3???

2. Is it possible to toggle "List of items"(drop down) in cell "F3" based on C3,D3,E3???